# V4 Azure function Timer Trigger configuration in AppSettings does not work in .NET 7

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((host, builder) =>
{
    builder
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{host.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true);
}).Build().Run();
```

Above is a portion of the code in my V4 Azure Function's Program.cs which runs on .NET 7.0

In my Azure Function, I use the %configurationName% convention to trigger this timer function every minute.

```
    [Function(nameof(FunctionATrigger))]
    public async Task Run(
        [TimerTrigger("%Values:TimerTriggerPeriod%", RunOnStartup = false)] TimerInfo timerInfo)
    {
    }
```

However, I keep getting the error:

> [2023-03-16T17:44:37.042Z] The 'FunctionATrigger' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.FunctionATrigger'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: '%Values:TimerTriggerPeriod%' does not resolve to a value.

I confirmed my host.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName is 'local'

In my appsettings.local.json I have:

```
{
   "Values": {
      "TimerTriggerPeriod": "0 * * * * *"
   }
}
```

I also tried %TimerTriggerPeriod% with the following appsetting without sucess :

```
{
   "TimerTriggerPeriod": "0 * * * * *"
}
```

Could this be something in .NET 7 and Azure Function V4?

As a test I verified I can access this value via Dependency Injection of IConfiguration

```
_configuration["Values:TimerTriggerPeriod"]
```

Comment: Have you tried with `%TimerTriggerPeriod%` and the first AppSettings (with TimerTriggerperiod inside Values)?

Comment: I did and I got the same error as well.

Comment: Did you mange to figure out the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work.  In my projects I have several setting files:

- appsettings.json
- appsettings.local.json
- launchSettings.json

I was able to get this working by adding the variable under the environmentVariables section:

```
{
"profiles": {
"My.Program.FunctionApp": {
  "launchBrowser": false,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT": "Local",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files",
    "FunctionTimerTrigger": "0 * * * * *"
    }
   }
  }
}
```

then I reference **%FunctionTimerTrigger%** in my timer function

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are loading appsettings.local.json. In order to verify you can add the config section to your secrets file or add them to appsettings.json.The following works for me:

```
[Function(nameof(FunctionATrigger))]
public async Task Run(
    [TimerTrigger("%MyFunctionName:DailyCronMidnightPST%"
    #if !RELEASE
        , RunOnStartup = true
    #endif
    )] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
}
```

appsettings.local.json:

```
{
    "MyFunctionName": {
        "4HourCronStartAt1AMPST": "0 0 8/4 * * *",
        "DailyCronMidnightPST": "0 0 7 * * *",
        "Throughput": 10000,
        "BatchSize": 100
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm, yours looks identical to me.  Are you running V4 on .NET 7?  As  test I put IConfiguration as DI and I was able to pull out the value when I do var test = _configuration["Values:TimerTriggerPeriod"];

Comment: It is most likely your cron timer that is the issue. Try hard coding the time string with a different value like: "0 */5 * * * *"